# MySQL: Access denied messages

Tags: mysql

I have just installed Ubuntu on my server and MySQL.

I can't make any change in MySQL (seeting password, creating database, etc.) as I ALWAYS get an Access denied error message. I have followed the MySQL manuals re passwords, but to no avail.

The user name I use is the account name created when Ubuntu was installed.

At some point, I am told I need SUPER privileges to do this or that but I can't change the privileges since I get the same error message. I can't even see the GRANTS as I also get the same access denied message.
mysql version 14.14 Dist. 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu

Any idea on how to solve this?

### To Arka:

Editing my own question is the only option I have to post this:

```
mysql> status

mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
Connection id: 63
Current database:
Current user: charles@localhost
SSL: Not in use
Current pager: stdout
Using outfile: ''
Using delimiter: ;
Server version: 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
Connection: localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset: latin1
Db characterset: latin1
Client characterset: utf8
Conn. characterset: utf8
UNIX socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime: 6 hours 58 min 20 sec
Threads: 1 
Questions: 165 
Slow queries: 0 
Opens: 211 
Flush tables: 1 
Open tables: 51 
Queries per second avg: 0.006
```

Now, I have not been able to create a single database since the installation of the server this morning. I hope that helps. Thanks. :)

Comment: Which MySQL client are you using ? The command-line `mysql` one ? Do you know your MySQL root password (it's not the same as the system's root password) ?

Comment: Please share the output. > mysql > status;

Comment: I am working directly with the server, either at the shell prompt ($) with phpmyadmin or after logging into the mysql server (mysql>) However, I can log into mysql without a password (but I did set up a password when I installed it. Puzzling and confusing... :)

Comment: To Arka: Editing my own original question is the only way for me to answer you. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you're installing MySQL you're asked to enter the `root` password that you want to set for the database. In the status code you've listed above you're logging in as `charles@localhost` and not `root`. That's the reason why it's not asking for the password you set during installation.

If you're logging in to MySQL using the `root` account then you can do all the things you want.

Simply type:

```
mysql -p -u root
```

and it'll ask you for the root password. Now you're "in" the system with full access. You can then create databases using:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyNewDatabase;
```

If you have a user that you want to give access to this new database you can type:

```
GRANT ALL ON MyNewDatabase.* TO 'charles'@'localhost';
```

When this is done you should be able to login as charles and also have full access to the newly created database.